# NHANES library is missing

Tags: r, dataset

My textbook ([*Statistics Using Technology*](https://www.coconino.edu/open-source-textbooks#statistics-using-technology-3rd-edition-by-kathryn-kozak), Third Edition by Kathryn Kozak) says that I should be able to type `library("NHANES")` after installing the `mosaic` package. This does not work on my machine. RStudio says I have `mosaic` version 1.6.0 installed.

I notice that [0.9.0](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mosaic/versions/0.9-0) lists NHANES as a "function" of MOSAIC while [1.6.0](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mosaic/versions/1.6.0) does not. I am a complete novice with R. Is there an alternative way to get `library("NHANES")` working?

Comment: Is it `library` or `data("NHANES")`? In any case, do you need this: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NHANES/NHANES.pdf?

Comment: That worked! All I needed to do was enter `install.packages("NHANES")` and now the command `library(NHANES)` works. I'll be happy to accept your comment as an answer.